# Heroku Clojure application exit hook

Tags: heroku, clojure

The entrance point for my clojure app is -main, but is there a function that is called upon the application's exit?  I need to close some connections when my Heroku dyno goes down, but can't figure out where or how to do that.

Comment: You may want to try using a JVM shutdown hook, if your JVM shuts down gracefully.

Comment: thanks.  i'd give you a plus 1 if i could...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Diego Basch said, use a JVM shutdown hook.

This is what I usually do when I need to do so:

```
(defn -main
  [& args]
  ((start ...)
   (.. (Runtime/getRuntime) (addShutdownHook (proxy [Thread] []
                                                 (run []
                                                   (stop ...)))))))
```